# What ist this component on early network cards with a slit in its package?

Tags: identification, components, ethernet, pc

Early PC network cards (10BASE2, with a BNC connector) often had a two-pin component, typically yellow, with a slit in its package, close to the connector ([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:12_early_PC_network_cards.jpg)):
[image: The component in question]

What is this component, and what is the purpose of the slit?

Comment: I've seen broken capacitors that look like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a designator of C38 which means it is a high voltage capacitor with a spark gap.

Typically the coaxial cable interface is isolated from the PC chassis ground, with the exception that the cable shield is connected to PC chassis via a 1 Mohm resistor in parallel with a 10nF high voltagre capacitor. The capacitor voltage rating typically is 1-2 kilovolts. The 10nF capacitor slows down the AC transients and the 1Mohm slowly discharges the charges that have accumulated. In the event of high surge voltage, it is discharged to PC chassis via the spark gap.

Comment: I learned a little, reading this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

it's a spark gap.  I'm sure this has been answered before.

Comment: Good call +1. https://images.bonanzastatic.com/afu/images/1974/5050/56/spark_Gap.png

Comment: Even using the term "spark gap", I wasn't able to find a previous answer to this (or a similar) question.

Comment: sometimes questions get deleted.